# Is this metric space complete? I don't think it's equivalent to the Euclidean metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $d(x,y)=\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_0^{+}$. Is this metric space complete?

I'm trying to find a counterexample, because my intuition says it's not complete. Also I know that $d(x,y)\leq 1$. What should I do?

Comment: $f$ maps $\mathbb R^+_0$ to $(0,1]$. Is that a complete set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\{n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the distance $d$: for $\epsilon>0$ and  for $n,m\geq N>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon/2}}$,
$$d(n,m)=\left|\frac{1}{1+n^2}-\frac{1}{1+m^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{m^2}<\epsilon.$$
Is it convergent in $(\mathbb{R}^+_0,d)$?  No, because for all $x\geq 0$ then
$$d(n,x)=\left|\frac{1}{1+n^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right|\to \frac{1}{1+x^2}>0.$$

Comment: Doesn't it converge to $0$ ?

Comment: @Gabriel Romon $d(n,0)=|1/(1+n^2)-1|\to 1$, so $n\not \to 0$

Comment: Of course, my mistake !

Comment: @alan Any further doubt?

Comment: @RobertZ No doubts :) thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Your space was defined in such a way that $f$ is an isometry between $[0,1)$ (endowed with its usual metric) and $(\mathbb{R}_0^+,d)$. Since $[0,1)$ is not complete, neither is your space.